# How can I update cache with CachePut?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

My @Cacheable method has next signature:

```
@Component
public class UpcomingFilter implements Filter<Entity> {

    @Cacheable(value = {"upcoming"})
    @Override
    public List<Entity> filter(int limit) {
       //retrieve from repository
    }
}
```

This filter use the reporisoty, take limit as parameter for pagination and return List of Entities. 
I'm trying to update cache when add Entity to the system:

```
@CachePut(value={"upcoming", "popular", "recentlyAdded", "recommendations", "thisWeek", "topRated"})
    public Entity addEntity(RequestDto dto, User user) {
        //do work, create and save entity to repository
        return entity;
    }
```

But after adding new entity to the system it is not updated. Filters returns old values. 
I saw examples, where for CachePut and Cacheable the word 'key' is used, but how can I add

```
@Cacheable(key="#entity.id")
```

to the **Filter** signature ?

**UPDATE**

Tried to add my key:

```
@CachePut(value={"upcoming","popular", "recentlyAdded", "recommendations", "thisWeek", "topRated"},
            key = "#root.target.FILTER_KEY", condition = "#result != null")
    public Entity addEntity(RequestDto dto, User user) {
            //do work, create and save entity to repository
            return entity;
        }
```

and also add key to @Cacheable:

```
public static final String FILTER_KEY = "filterKey";
@Cacheable(value = {"recentlyAdded"}, key = "#root.target.FILTER_KEY")
    @Override
    public List<Entity> filter(int limit) {
```

and than I get

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.java.domain.Entity cannot be cast to
>   java.util.List

Comment: Can you give more details on what you are going to cache and by what key? If you are updating/adding any entity you might have to evict the list<Entity> if you are caching this list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead @CachePut the @CacheEvict should be used. 
It works for me:

```
 @CacheEvict(value={"upcoming", "popular", "recentlyAdded", "recommendations", "thisWeek", "topRated"},
            allEntries = true, condition = "#result != null")
        public Entity addEntity(RequestDto dto, User user) {
            //do work, create and save entity to repository
            return entity;
        }
```